# Getting colored results when using a pipe from grep to less

Tags: colors, grep, pipe, less

I use the --colour option of grep a lot, but I often use less as well. How can I pipe grep results to less and still preserve the coloring. (Or is that possible?)

```
grep "search-string" -R * --colour | less
```

**EDIT**:

I'm looking for a direct solution or anything equivalent to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get colors in 'less'' command](http://superuser.com/questions/117841/get-colors-in-less-command)

Comment: What does `*` do? From the man page of grep: `*: The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.` But I still don't understand..! @JeremyPowell

Comment: @Shayan, the '*' in this case is for the file arguments. It gets processed by the shell which expands it to all files in the directory. The search string is enclosed in double quotes in the example.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

When you simply run `grep --color` it implies `grep --color=auto` which detects whether the output is a terminal and if so enables colors. However, when it detects a pipe it disables coloring. The following command:

```
grep --color=always -R "search string" * | less
```

Will always enable coloring and override the automatic detection, and you will get the color highlighting in `less`.

**EDIT:** Although using just `less` works for me, perhaps older version require the `-R` flag to handle colors, as therefromhere suggested.

Comment: You need to use `less -R` for the colour encoding to be interpreted by less correctly

Comment: It worked for me with just `less`, it may be version dependent.

Comment: wow. I thought 'auto' only depended on the terminal type. I may be jumping the gun, but this may revolutionize the way I use linux :P

Comment: Awesome. Though I too to use `less -R` to get `less` to display colours, rather than the colouring escape codes :o)

Comment: A (hopefully) useful addendum: I needed to exclude some matches but maintain the colouring, so I actually ended up with `grep pattern file | grep -v badpattern | grep --colour=always pattern | less -R`, which met my needs perfectly. (Thanks again!)

Comment: I can't believe they just implemented the color-handling feature in `less` and therefore missed the chance to have a special `colorless` tool. For the name alone it should have been done! I should probably write a patch that invokes -R automatically when the binary is run as `colorless`.

Comment: Yay, works for git log -p too. :)

Comment: @OwenBlacker the reason it 'just' works for you is probably because some linux distros setup some default aliases. Do `alias less` in a terminal and see what you get.

Comment: Using grep without `-R` and `more` instead of `less -R` works for me... and its shorter. In other words, this works on Fedora 20 `grep --color=always -Irn "foo_bar" | more`

Comment: @spatz: You could integrate [Dennis answer](http://superuser.com/a/36201/102954) into yours to make it a one-stop-shop. Integration answers are perfectly wanted on SO. Thanks! That would solve the problem Owen addressed in his comment.

Comment: @OwenBlacker It might not be an alias. You might have `$LESS` set with `-R`.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 `cat file.log | grep --color=always password | less -R`

Comment: To make `less` default to always pass through colors, edit your `LESS` environment variable to include `-R` or its long form `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS`. The `LESS` variable contains a space-separated list of default flags for `less`.

Comment: old Q and answer, but thank you! works like a charm.

Comment: is it only me or does this break pattern matching in subsequent greps in the pipe?

Answer (score 35):

You can put this in your `.bashrc` file:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always"
```

or create an alias like this:

```
alias grepc="grep --color=always"
```

and you will need to use the `-R` option for `less`, as pointed out by therefromhere

Comment: Warning!: GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always" may break _many_ scripts that use grep (or (e|f)grep).

Comment: Yeah, better to just alias grep.  You can always get pure `grep` with `GREP`, or override the `--color` option manually.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, alias does work though.

Answer (score 16):

In case like this, I prefer to actually create small sh files and put them on `/usr/local/bin`.
I usually use `grep` in the recursive way on the `pwd`, so thats my personal script:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color=always -r "$@" . | less -R
```

And then I've just copied it as `/usr/local/bin/g` (yes, I use it a lot)

Comment: Why not just use shell functions for this kind of thing? `g() { grep --color=always -r "$@" . | less -R }` works identically and probably will give (minutely) better performance.

Comment: @00dani yeah, that's a valid alternative too and sometimes I use it. Please note that in this case, most time is spent in IO and therefore there is no perceivable performance boost :) Another difference is that once in your PATH, this script can be used with other shell scripts and aliases too; the function instead needs to be explicitly loaded

Answer (score 2):

Don't alias "grep", better to alias "less" which is never used by shells. In your `.bashrc` just put:  `alias less="less -r"`.

Comment: Not quite right. One needs to use _both_ `grep --color=always` and `less -R`. Note that grep only knows it is being piped into some other process and the `--color=auto` option uses solely this information to decide if will output colors or not.

Comment: Note that `less` option `-r` is different than `-R`. Probably `-R` is safer.

Comment: So why down-vote my solution. The OP specifically ask for `less` with the example already using `--color' option.

Comment: An alias is probably undesirable here. `less` supports a `$LESS` environment variable. So, instead of an alias, `export LESS='-R'` might be preferable.

Comment: @greyfade "an alias is probably undesirable here" why? envvars are more flexible to be sure, but you can `unalias` a command if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
grep --color=always -R "search string" * | less -r
```

with the `-r` flag after `less`, in order for this to work.

Comment: What does `*` do? From the man page of grep: `*: The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.` But I still don't understand..!

Comment: @Shayan It will search for the text "search string" in all files.