# When reading a file with `less` or `more`, how can I get the content in colors?

Tags: linux, colors, less

When I read a file in Linux with the command `less` or `more`, how can I get the content in colors?

Comment: This seems related: http://superuser.com/questions/36022/less-and-grep-color - does it help?

Comment: The title of this question is very misleading. Many people landing on this page expect a solution to the coloring issue you will get when **piping** a command with colored output to `less`: colors are lost. (The answers to that ”piping issue“ involve `less -R`, `unbuffer` etc.) But the actual question refers to **opening a file**! — The ambiguity lies primarily in the question's title, but even besides that, IMHO the question is still too broad: ”read a file“ could refer to *any* file (probably plain text). (well, ”get the content in colors“ is probably referring to syntax highlighting.)

Comment: I need to correct myself, only 3 (or 4) of 14 answers are missing the OP's actual question: the answers by [ChristopheD](https://superuser.com/a/117842/208765), [Puneet](https://superuser.com/a/275869/208765) and [Onlyjob](https://superuser.com/a/635063/208765); and maybe [jbbr](https://superuser.com/a/1132741/208765). Still, two of those answers are part of the three highest-voted ones.

Comment: @myrdd "syntax highlighting" is the relevant term then... (It asks about showing colors, not adding colors?) `less -R` will work on files as well, e.g. `ls --color=always > /tmp/file && less -R /tmp/file`

Comment: @GertvandenBerg I think the OP meant ”*how to get syntax highlighting in `less` or `more` when the file opened does NOT contain any escape codes*“. But I only *think* he meant that, I don't know it. — By the way, I disagree with you interpretation of the question. The question says ”**When I read a file […]**“, and by ”file“ I'm quite sure the OP meant a *typical* plaintext file, or a ”normal“ file. Does a ”typical“ plaintext file (or ”normal“ file) contain escape characters, i.e., coloring? No. So IMHO the question **is** about ”adding“ colors (or syntax highlighting).

Comment: @myrdd It might make most sense for the question to be closed as "unclear what is being asked" since questions asking any of the two would likely get marked as duplicates of this...  (And answers for any of the two can get downvoted based on how the voter interprets it...) (My use case was a log file that (annoyingly) has color escape codes in it)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg I agree. I already have been voting for closing the question.

Comment: Seems like duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/71588/105108.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

If you just want to tell `less` to interpret color codes, use `less -R`. [ref.](https://superuser.com/a/117842/34893)

---

You can utilize the power of pygmentize with less - automatically! (No need to pipe by hand.)

Install `pygments` with your package manager or pip (possibly called `python-pygments`) or get it here http://pygments.org/download/.

Write a file `~/.lessfilter`

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    *.awk|*.groff|*.java|*.js|*.m4|*.php|*.pl|*.pm|*.pod|*.sh|\
    *.ad[asb]|*.asm|*.inc|*.[ch]|*.[ch]pp|*.[ch]xx|*.cc|*.hh|\
    *.lsp|*.l|*.pas|*.p|*.xml|*.xps|*.xsl|*.axp|*.ppd|*.pov|\
    *.diff|*.patch|*.py|*.rb|*.sql|*.ebuild|*.eclass)
        pygmentize -f 256 "$1";;

    .bashrc|.bash_aliases|.bash_environment)
        pygmentize -f 256 -l sh "$1";;

    *)
        if grep -q "#\!/bin/bash" "$1" 2> /dev/null; then
            pygmentize -f 256 -l sh "$1"
        else
            exit 1
        fi
esac

exit 0
```

In your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc` or equivalent) add

```
export LESS='-R'
export LESSOPEN='|~/.lessfilter %s'
```

Also, you need to make `~/.lessfilter` executable by running

```
chmod u+x ~/.lessfilter
```

---

Edit: If you have `lesspipe` on your system, you might want to use that to automatically unzip archives when looking at them with less, e.g. `less log.gz`. lesspipe also supports a custom `.lessfilter` file, so everything said above works the same, you just have to run

```
eval "$(lesspipe)"
```

in your rc file instead of setting the `LESSOPEN` variable. Run `echo "$(lesspipe)"` to see what it does. Your `.lessfilter` will still work. See `man lesspipe`.

---

Tested on Debian.

You get the idea. This can of course be improved further, accepting more extensions, multiple files, or parsing the shebang for other interpreters than bash. See some of the other answers for that.

The idea came from an old blog post from the [makers of Pygments](http://www.pocoo.org/), but the original post doesn't exist anymore.

---

Btw. you can also use this technique to [show directory listings](https://superuser.com/a/583929/98217) with `less`.

Comment: If you want to have coloring of the source code files, you also need to make ~/.lessfilter executable by running `chmod u+x ~/.lessfilter`. You also need to have pygmentize (http://pygments.org/download/) installed.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this works as it has no effect for me when I execute a command like `ls -l | less`

Comment: Any idea how to chain this with Vladimir Linek's lessopen.sh?? it is setup with this form: LESSOPEN="lessopen.sh %s"

Comment: @puk you can do something like `ls --color=always -l | less -R`. Obviously a lot to type but you could alias it to something like `ll`. That is if you don't want to use any extra libraries.

Comment: The -g flag on pygmentize will solve the problem of "Error: no lexer for filename" for filetypes not included, as described here http://askubuntu.com/a/392017/115392

Comment: added @SergiyByelozyorov's comment into the answer.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested, I wrote a pair of scripts that serves a very similar purpose ([pygmentize-addons](https://github.com/brbsix/pygmentize-addons)). They are wrappers around `pygmentize`, used to view syntax highlighted code for files or scripts on PATH via stdout, `less`, or PNG image. I use it all the time to examine source code of files and installed scripts.

Comment: dont forget to `sudo aptitude install python-pygments`

Comment: is there an easy way to obtain more saturated colors on the default color scheme (php) to view in console?

Comment: My edit was rejected so I guess I'll post it as a comment instead: Don't test the exit codes of commands indirectly. You can use `if grep -q "#\!/bin/bash" "$1"` (the `-q` suppresses standard output). You may want to redirect standard error with `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: @TomFenech good point, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: It took me a long time to troubleshoot back to this, after noticing `less` could no longer decompress .gz,bz2,xz,etc. files on the fly.  How to have both color and prior LESSPIPE features?

Comment: To get a list of all unique file extensions supported by your currently installed pygmentize version, in a format suitable for pasting into this .lessfilter script, run `pygmentize -L | grep -o "(filenames .*)" | sed -E "s,\(filenames (.*)\),\1,gm;s/, /\n/g" | sort -u | tr "\n" "|"`. Note that on certain Linuxes, setting `LESSOPEN` may not be necessary because it is already setup to use `lesspipe` which detects the .lessfilter file already (run `echo $LESSOPEN` to check).

Comment: Make sure to add the `-R` before any files specified, or does  not work after the file

Comment: Can we use it in zsh shell?

Comment: @alper Sure, this is a feature of `less`, it works in any shell. `less` just executes whatever script you specify in the `LESSOPEN` environment variable.

Comment: @Marcos oh, right, I hadn't noticed that. It's actually very easy to support both, the lesspipe to handle archives and the .lessfilter to have colors (because lesspipe supports a custom lessfilter, see `man lesspipe`). I'll update the answer again.

Comment: Yeesh... <shudder>

Comment: This is an excellent answer with a very useful example! Thanks! I think I'm going to try to make a lessfilter for jq and have it pretty print json chunk

Answer (score 589):

Try the following:

```
less -R
```

from `man less`:

> `-r` or `--raw-control-chars`
>
> Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed. (...)
>
> `-R` or `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS`
>
> Like `-r`, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form. (...)

Comment: it does not work

there is some conf file for "less" like for vim there is .vimrc ?

Comment: This is useful when the file itself contains the escape codes that will need to be displayed.

Comment: interesting, a test for `less` file contains escape characters: `script` `ls --color` `exit` `less -R typedscript`

Comment: I used to know about less -r but searching in the file using "/" kept bringing up the wrong lines. -R seems to do a better job. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It should be noted that most programs use the `isatty(2)` syscall to check whether their standard output is a terminal, and usually disable colorized output if it is not. For any pipe to less, `isatty` will return 0. To check whether this works, try `echo -e '\x1b[32;1mtest\x1b[m' | less -r`

Comment: Using the lower case '-r' for me means that the ^M characters from windows files are not shown. I like this because I'm not bothered about line endings and it makes the rest of the output a bit clearer.

Comment: This answer does not excel in the actually does something test.

Comment: Very useful combined with `unbuffer`

Comment: You can also type `-R` when you already opened `less` to achieve this.

Comment: IMHO this should actually be the accepted answer, it is much more simple

Comment: As Nitrodist said this is useful only if tte escape codes for coloring are present. So if you want the git diff's output in less, you have to use git diff --color | less -R

Comment: This worked for me with grep only when I included the `--color=always` option in grep.: `grep --color=always foo myfile.txt | less -R`

Comment: cool and should-be accepted one to me

Comment: Neither `-R` nor `-r` work when outputting a object in NodeJS/Deno/Bun, e.g. : `node -e "console.log({ 'foo': 'bar' })"`. Help ? Thanks

Answer (score 166):

I got the answer in another post: [Less and Grep: Getting colored results when using a pipe from grep to less](https://superuser.com/questions/36022/less-and-grep-color)

> When you simply run `grep --color` it
>   implies `grep --color=auto` which
>   detects whether the output is a
>   terminal and if so enables colors.
>   However, when it detects a pipe it
>   disables coloring. The following
>   command:
>
> ```
> grep --color=always "search string" * | less -R
> ```
>
> Will always enable coloring and
>   override the automatic detection, and
>   you will get the color highlighting in
>   less.

Warning: Don't put `--color=always` as an alias, it break things sometimes. That's why there is an `--color=auto` option.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Except that I need to use `-R` as an option to `less`, as well.

Comment: I believe `grep -R` is for specifying recursive search. `less -R` is necessary for `less` to correctly spit the colors back out. `grep --color=always [grep cmds] | less -R` works for me on OS X 10.7.3!

Comment: @naught101 @Steven Lu Edited in, though it seems that some people may not need to use `less -R` (according to the author of the original post, anyway).

Comment: Is there anyway to let grep know just pipe less -R command and then just do coloring? So, we don't have to put --color=always and less -R all the time.

Comment: This is by far the simplest working answer. Thanks!

Comment: This also works when you need to pipe `git diff` to `less`. Doing just this: `git diff | less` won't show you any colors. You need to do this instead: `git diff --colors=always | less` or `git diff --colors=always some_file | less`. (I'm using cygwin on Windows 10, by the way.)

Comment: Correction/update of @CSCH comment: the correct option to `git diff` is `--color=always` (no 's' to 'color').

Comment: `--color=always` works for `diff` (non-Git) command as well.

Answer (score 47):

Use `view` instead of `less`. It opens the file with `vim` in readonly mode.

It's practically a coloured `less`: a pager where you can search with <kbd>/</kbd> (and more). The only drawback is that you can't exit with <kbd>q</kbd> but you need `:q`

Also, you get the same colouring as `vim` (since you're in fact using `vim`).

Comment: How about the performance of big files? Vim syntax highlighting is know to be slow on huge files.

Comment: I don't know what's your value for 'big', but opening a ~10000 lines file is instantaneous, search inside included.

Comment: Note that you may need to add `view -` when piping

Comment: `vim` is an editor, which loads the complete file into memory, whereas `less` is a pager, loading the file only partially into memory. You will know the difference with huge files.

Comment: @RiccardoGalli - Cool idea, but i would agree about the performance concern, it's not instantaneous. When viewing huge logs or greps, especially over-the-line (SSH), `less` is faster since it's not dumping the entire output line by line via "inserts" into `vim`. Also, you can search with `less` using '/'. Additionally it has a "tail" mode using shift-F which is handy.

Comment: `gmic -h | view` starts to execute `vim` commands. It is not safe. `gmic -h | view -` doesn't color on Ubuntu 18.10, so downvoting.

Comment: at least on debian, `view` is a [Debian Alternative](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives), that is, `/usr/bin/view` points to `/etc/alternatives/view`. Try `sudo update-alternatives --config view`.

Comment: `ls --color=always > /tmp/file && view /tmp/file` certainly does not work.... It shows the escape codes instead of rendering them.

Answer (score 37):

To tell less to show colors call it with -R:

```
less -R
```

Unfortunately some programs detect that their stdout is not a terminal and disable colors - e.g pacman (Arch Linux package manager).

In those cases its possible to use `unbuffer`:

```
unbuffer <command> | less -R
```

Example using pacman

```
unbuffer pacman -Ss firefox | less -R
```

The `unbuffer` command is usually part of the package `expect` (Arch Linux, Debian/Ubuntu) or `expect-dev` (legacy versions of Debian/Ubuntu).

To answer the question for completeness:

As others already answered, `pygmentize` is great for colorizing source code. It does not require `unbuffer`. Easiest call:

```
pygmentize someSource.cpp | less -R
```

Comment: To use `unbuffer` on Ubuntu, `sudo apt install expect`

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes.

Comment: I was trying to pipe dmesg output to check on boot errors but the colours didn't work unless I use unbuffer, which was confusing the heck out of me: `unbuffer dmesg | less -R` works as expected.

Comment: on macOS `brew install expect` gets you the necessary `unbuffer` command.

Comment: On macOS, the `brew install expect` installed doesn't work, maybe because I have `conda` installed. There seems to be no `expect` installable from `conda` that could fix this unfortunately. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047900/unbuffer-stopped-working-months-ago

Answer (score 22):

`pygmentize` supports the `-g` option to automatically guess the lexer to be used which is useful for files read from `STDIN` without checking any extension type.

Using that, you only need to set the following 2 exports in your `.bashrc` without any additional scripts:

```
export LESS='-R'
export LESSOPEN='|pygmentize -g %s'
```

Comment: Concise and effective. I prefer defining an alias, because sometimes less is better. So: alias lesc='LESS="-R" LESSOPEN="|pygmentize -g %s" less'

Answer (score 11):

You didn't say what this color should mean, e.g. what should the colors be for a text file?

If what you want is syntax highlighting for source code, you need a source code highlighter. I sometimes use [pygmentize](http://pygments.org) like this

```
pygmentize file.cpp | less
```

or

```
pygmentize file.cpp | more
```

There are other highlighters around.

This is pretty fast. If you don't mind firing up `vim` there is a read-only mode that can give you syntax highlighting if you have it in `vim`.

```
view file.cpp
```

or alternatively see churnd's answer.

Answer (score 10):

This is yet another [pygments](http://pygments.org/)-based answer, with several major improvements:

- does not break `lesspipe` or `lessfile` filters
- works with multiple inputs to `less`
- correctly parses the script type from the shebang header
- works for all 434 file types lexable by Pygments
- color scheme is parameterized as an environment variable

EDIT:
I maintain an updated/improved version of this script here:
https://github.com/CoeJoder/lessfilter-pygmentize

Original version below:

## Install Pygments and Gawk

```sh
sudo apt-get install python-pygments python3-pygments gawk
```

## Set Environment Variables

Check whether `lesspipe` or `lessfile` is already enabled:

```sh
echo $LESSOPEN
```

If you don't see either program referenced there, ensure that [`lesspipe`](https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe) is installed (most distros come with it).

Add the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
# sets LESSOPEN and LESSCLOSE variables
eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# interpret color characters
export LESS='-R'

# to list available styles: `pygmentize -L styles`
export PYGMENTIZE_STYLE='paraiso-dark'

# optional
alias ls='ls --color=always'
alias grep='grep --color=always'
```

If you don't want `lesspipe`, replace the `eval` statement with:

```sh
export LESSOPEN='|~/.lessfilter %s'
```

## Create `~/.lessfilter`

Add the following code and make the file executable: `chmod u+x ~/.lessfilter`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for path in "$@"; do
    # match by known filenames
    filename=$(basename "$path")
    case "$filename" in
        .bashrc|bash.bashrc|.bash_aliases|.bash_environment|.bash_profile|\
        .bash_login|.bash_logout|.profile|.zshrc|.zprofile|.zshrc|.zlogin|\
        .zlogout|zshrc|zprofile|zshrc|zlogin|zlogout|.cshrc|.cshdirs|\
        csh.cshrc|csh.login|csh.logout|.tcshrc|.kshrc|ksh.kshrc)
            # shell lexer
            pygmentize -f 256 -O style=$PYGMENTIZE_STYLE -l sh "$path"
            ;;
        .htaccess|apache.conf|apache2.conf|Dockerfile|Kconfig|external.in*|\
        standard-modules.in|nginx.conf|pacman.conf|squid.conf|termcap|\
        termcap.src|terminfo|terminfo.src|control|sources.list|CMakeLists.txt|\
        Makefile|makefile|Makefile.*|GNUmakefile|SConstruct|SConscript|\
        .Rhistory|.Rprofile|.Renviron|Rakefile|Gemfile|PKGBUILD|autohandler|\
        dhandler|autodelegate|.vimrc|.exrc|.gvimrc|vimrc|exrc|gvimrc|todo.txt)
            # filename recognized
            pygmentize -f 256 -O style=$PYGMENTIZE_STYLE "$path"
            ;;
        *)
            ext=$([[ "$filename" = *.* ]] && echo ".${filename##*.}" || echo '')
            case "$ext" in
                .as|.mxml|.bc|.g|.gd|.gi|.gap|.nb|.cdf|.nbp|.ma|.mu|.at|.run|\
                .apl|.adl|.adls|.adlf|.adlx|.cadl|.odin|.c-objdump|.s|\
                .cpp-objdump|.c++-objdump|.cxx-objdump|.d-objdump|.S|.hsail|\
                .ll|.asm|.ASM|.objdump-intel|.objdump|.tasm|.au3|.ahk|.ahkl|\
                .bb|.decls|.bmx|.bas|.monkey|.BAS|.bst|.bib|.abap|.ABAP|.cbl|\
                .CBL|.cob|.COB|.cpy|.CPY|.gdc|.maql|.p|.cls|.c|.h|.idc|.cpp|\
                .hpp|.c++|.h++|.cc|.hh|.cxx|.hxx|.C|.H|.cp|.CPP|.ino|.clay|\
                .cu|.cuh|.ec|.eh|.mq4|.mq5|.mqh|.nc|.pike|.pmod|.swg|.i|.vala|\
                .vapi|.capnp|.chpl|.icl|.dcl|.cf|.docker|.ini|.cfg|.inf|\
                .pc|.properties|.reg|.tf|.pypylog|.cr|.csd|.orc|.sco|.css|\
                .less|.sass|.scss|.croc|.d|.di|.smali|.jsonld|.json|.yaml|\
                .yml|.dpatch|.darcspatch|.diff|.patch|.wdiff|.boo|.aspx|.asax|\
                .ascx|.ashx|.asmx|.axd|.cs|.fs|.fsi|.n|.vb|.als|.bro|.crmsh|\
                .pcmk|.msc|.pan|.proto|.pp|.rsl|.sbl|.thrift|.rpf|\
                .dylan-console|.dylan|.dyl|.intr|.lid|.hdp|.ecl|.e|.elm|.ex|\
                .exs|.erl|.hrl|.es|.escript|.erl-sh|.aheui|.befunge|.bf|.b|\
                .camkes|.idl4|.cdl|.cw|.factor|.fan|.flx|.flxh|.frt|.f|.F|\
                .f03|.f90|.F03|.F90|.PRG|.prg|.go|.abnf|.bnf|.jsgf|.cyp|\
                .cypher|.asy|.vert|.frag|.geo|.plot|.plt|.ps|.eps|.pov|.inc|\
                .agda|.cry|.hs|.idr|.kk|.kki|.lagda|.lcry|.lhs|.lidr|.hx|\
                .hxsl|.hxml|.sv|.svh|.v|.vhdl|.vhd|.dtd|.haml|.html|.htm|\
                .xhtml|.xslt|.pug|.jade|.scaml|.xml|.xsl|.rss|.xsd|.wsdl|\
                .wsf|.xpl|.pro|.ipf|.nsi|.nsh|.spec|.i6t|.ni|.i7x|.t|.io|\
                .ijs|.coffee|.dart|.eg|.js|.jsm|.juttle|.kal|.lasso|\
                .lasso[89]|.ls|.mask|.j|.ts|.tsx|.jl|.aj|.ceylon|.clj|\
                .cljs|.golo|.gs|.gsx|.gsp|.vark|.gst|.groovy|.gradle|.ik|\
                .java|.kt|.pig|.scala|.xtend|.cpsa|.cl|.lisp|.el|.hy|.lsp|.nl|\
                .kif|.rkt|.rktd|.rktl|.scm|.ss|.shen|.xtm|.cmake|.mak|.mk|\
                .[1234567]|.man|.md|.css.in|.js.in|.xul.in|.rst|.rest|.tex|\
                .aux|.toc|.m|.sci|.sce|.tst|.ml|.mli|.mll|.mly|.opa|.sml|.sig|\
                .fun|.bug|.jag|.mo|.stan|.def|.mod|.mt|.ncl|.nim|.nimrod|.nit|\
                .nix|.cps|.x|.xi|.xm|.xmi|.mm|.swift|.ooc|.psi|.psl|.G|.ebnf|\
                .rl|.treetop|.tt|.adb|.ads|.ada|.pas|.dpr|.pwn|.sp|.pl|.pm|\
                .nqp|.p6|.6pl|.p6l|.pl6|.6pm|.p6m|.pm6|.php|.php[345]|.zep|\
                .praat|.proc|.psc|.lgt|.logtalk|.prolog|.pyx|.pxd|.pxi|.dg|\
                .py3tb|.py|.pyw|.sc|.tac|.sage|.pytb|.qvto|.Rout|.Rd|.R|.rq|\
                .sparql|.ttl|.r|.r3|.reb|.red|.reds|.txt|.rnc|.graph|\
                .instances|.robot|.fy|.fancypack|.rb|.rbw|.rake|.gemspec|\
                .rbx|.duby|.rs|.rs.in|.SAS|.sas|.applescript|.chai|.ezt|\
                .mac|.hyb|.jcl|.lsl|.lua|.wlua|.moo|.moon|.rexx|.rex|.rx|\
                .arexx|.sh|.ksh|.bash|.ebuild|.eclass|.exheres-0|.exlib|.zsh|\
                .sh-session|.shell-session|.bat|.cmd|.fish|.load|.ps1|.psm1|\
                .tcsh|.csh|.ns2|.st|.smv|.snobol|.rql|.sql|.sqlite3-console|\
                .do|.ado|.scd|.tcl|.rvt|.ng2|.tmpl|.spt|.cfc|.cfm|.cfml|\
                .evoque|.kid|.handlebars|.hbs|.phtml|.jsp|.liquid|.mao|.mhtml|\
                .mc|.mi|.myt|.rhtml|.tpl|.ssp|.tea|.twig|.vm|.fhtml|.sls|\
                .feature|.tap|.awk|.vim|.pot|.po|.weechatlog|.todotxt|.thy|\
                .lean|.rts|.u|.vcl|.bpl|.sil|.vpr|.cirru|.duel|.jbst|.qml|\
                .qbs|.slim|.xqy|.xquery|.xq|.xql|.xqm|.whiley|.x10)
                    # extension recognized
                    pygmentize -f 256 -O style=$PYGMENTIZE_STYLE "$path"
                    ;;
                *)
                    # parse the shebang script header if it exists
                    lexer=$(head -n 1 "$path" |grep "^#\!" |awk -F" " \
'match($1, /\/(\w*)$/, a) {if (a[1]!="env") {print a[1]} else {print $2}}')
                    case "$lexer" in
                        node|nodejs)
                            # workaround for lack of Node.js lexer alias
                            pygmentize -f 256 -O style=$PYGMENTIZE_STYLE \
                                -l js "$path"
                            ;;
                        "")
                            exit 1
                            ;;
                        *)
                            pygmentize -f 256 -O style=$PYGMENTIZE_STYLE \
                                -l $lexer "$path"
                            ;;
                    esac
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
    esac
done
exit 0
```

Comment: TIL: If you get an error like "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ," with the above .lessfilter in place, check that gawk is installed.

Answer (score 5):

To expand upon another answer, you can make it work for most if not all of your scripts that don't have extensions by changing the .lessfilter file around just a bit:

```
#!/bin/sh
    case "$1" in
    *.awk|*.groff|*.java|*.js|*.m4|*.php|*.pl|*.pm|*.pod|*.sh|\
    *.ad[asb]|*.asm|*.inc|*.[ch]|*.[ch]pp|*.[ch]xx|*.cc|*.hh|\
    *.lsp|*.l|*.pas|*.p|*.xml|*.xps|*.xsl|*.axp|*.ppd|*.pov|\
    *.diff|*.patch|*.py|*.rb|*.sql|*.ebuild|*.eclass)
        pygmentize -f 256 "$1";;
    .bashrc|.bash_aliases|.bash_environment)
        pygmentize -f 256 -l sh "$1"
        ;;
    *)
        scriptExec=$(head -1 "$1" |grep "^#\!" |awk -F" " '{print $1}')
        scriptExecStatus=$?
        if [ "$scriptExecStatus" -eq "0" ]; then
            lexer=$(echo $scriptExec |awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
            pygmentize -f 256 -l $lexer "$1"
        else
            exit 1
        fi
esac

exit 0
```

You'd still need to add the two variables to .bashrc:

```
export LESS='-R'
export LESSOPEN='|~/.lessfilter %s'
```

And you'll still need to make .lessfilter executable:

```
$ chmod 700 ~/.lessfilter
```

Also I wanted to add that under debian the pygments package is called python-pygments. I had trouble locating it at first because the obvious misspelling of "pigments" as "pygments" wasn't enough of a hint to me that it was a package that might be prefixed with "python-" by the package manager.

Comment: 2 comments: 1) Thanks for the improvement. 2) Phrases like "voted best answer" aren't great; that may change (in fact, if this is better than that answer, _this_ post might become the top answer, at which point it'll just be confusing. Maybe just say "to expand upon another answer" or "captaincomic's answer"?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [GNU Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/); you can install it with `apt` if you have it, or otherwise install it from source. Then set up an "input preprocessor" for less, with help from the Source-highligh' documentations for [setting up with less](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#Using-source_002dhighlight-with-less):

> This was suggested by Konstantine Serebriany. The script src-hilite-lesspipe.sh will be installed together with source-highlight. You can use the following environment variables:

```
 export LESSOPEN="| /path/to/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
 export LESS=' -R '
```

> This way, when you use less to browse a file, if it is a source file handled by source-highlight, it will be automatically highlighted.
>
> Xavier-Emmanuel Vincent recently provided an alternative version of ANSI color scheme, esc256.style: some terminals can handle 256 colors. Xavier also provided a script which checks how many colors your terminal can handle, and in case, uses the 256 variant. The script is called source-highlight-esc.sh and it will be installed together with the other binaries.

Answer (score 5):

*Condensed from my full blog post about improving less experience: https://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/09/27/make-gnu-less-more-powerful/*

For colorful manpages, add the following to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[1;31m'     # begin bold
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[1;36m'     # begin blink
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'        # reset bold/blink
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;44;33m' # begin reverse video
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'        # reset reverse video
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[1;32m'     # begin underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'        # reset underline
```

For syntax highlighting, using an existing powerful `lesspipe.sh` to handle it instead of writing your own: https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to less/more that works with colors out of the box is bat.  You can install it with most package managers use it as a pager as well as a cat replacement.

https://github.com/sharkdp/bat

Comment: Very fast and straigthforward !

Comment: bat behaves like cat when the content is small enough to fit inside your window; that is, writing to terminal without opening a pager. You can use the option `bat --paging=always` to always use a pager.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider using `most` utility which is colour-friendly alternative for `less` and `more`.

Comment: can you show us one example? I tried here, and the output was black and white.

Comment: Your input should contain colours. First produce a colorised sample (e.g. `ccze -A </var/log/dpkg.log`, `ls -1 --color /var/log`) then pipe it to `most`: `ls -1 --color /var/log | most`.

Comment: yes, I used: `git status | less --color`, `git status | most --color`

Comment: I used most, more, less, and all tools show black and white

Comment: Make sure that your command produces colours _before_ piping to `less` or others. Make sure your terminal emulator can output colours. Check `TERM` environment variable. Read more in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment
When possible use modern GNU+Linux distribution like [Debian](https://debian.org). Use search engine (e.g. https://duckduckgo.com/ https://www.startpage.com/) to find answers. Remember that comments are not for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I found this simple elegant solution. You don't have to install anything extra as it is already there by default on most machines. As `vim` is installed by default on most machines, it includes a macro to run `vim` like `less`

Some of the options to use it are to create an alias:
`alias vless='vim -u /usr/share/vim/vim74/macros/less.vim'`

or create a symbolic link:
`ln -s /usr/share/vim/vim74/macros/less.sh ~/bin/vless`

Then you just run `vless myfile.py`

I got most of the information [here](https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/07/14/use-vim-as-a-syntax-highlighting-pager/)

Comment: I have `alias lesser='/usr/share/vim/vim80/macros/less.sh'` in `~/bash_aliases` (in Ubuntu 18.04). Can use shortcuts such as f forward, b backward, d half down, u half up, q quit, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make `less` use more colors is to `--use-color`. For example, running

```bash
LESS='--use-color -RNJWj5 --header=2' man less
```

will, after trying a few commands (searching, scrolling, marking, etc.),
result in

[image]

`--use-color` enables colored text

`--header=2 -RNJWj3` enables extra features for demo purposes