# The Less command can list directory contents in Gentoo Linux, but not in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, unix, gentoo, less

I regularly use the 'less' command in Gentoo like so:
less /tmp
(or any other directory, which I have access to.)

Less then proceeds to show me the contents of that directory. I can also use Less to show the contents of files (the usual use case).

In Ubuntu (Oneiric) when executing the above command, Less reports:
/tmp is a directory

Less will not list the contents of the directory.

I am using Less version 444 in both operating systems.

Can anyone help? I have been unsuccessful searching online.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Lesspipe is part of the `less` package on Ubuntu (Precise, at least), and is probably already installed on your computer.

Put this command in a login script, for instance `~/.bash_login`:

```
eval $(lesspipe)
```

Then put this content in `~/.lessfilter`

```
#!/bin/sh

# show directory as listing
if test -d "$1"; then
 /bin/ls -alF -- "$1"

 # we handled this one ourself
 exit 0
fi

# handle by regular lesspipe
exit 1
```

And make this file executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.lessfilter
```

Directories should now be shown as long format listings.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `README.gentoo` file in

```
/usr/portage/sys-apps/less/files
```

The behavior of `less` is customized by a `lesspipe.sh` script (in that same directory). If the argument passed is a directory, `lesspipe.sh` does `ls -alF` on it and that is what `less` pages.

See the [less man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less), *Input preprocessor* section for additional information. You can probably pick up Gentoo's `lesspipe.sh` and put it on your Ubuntu system without much hassle.