# *live* vim syntax highlighting on stdout?

Tags: bash, vim, terminal, colors, syntax-highlighting

I want to have some program's output colorized as it apperas on terminal.

I know that utility named [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/) does the this. But: it has a limited set of built-in language support, and I want coloring for e.g. some work-related daemon logs, for which I already made complex vim syntax files.

I know it is possible to use vim for syntax highlighting as less replacement (vimpager) or directly in terminal ([vimcat](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4325)). But, both these ways vim waits until EOF, and then display colored file -- it's useless for e.g. live daemon testing.

So: is it possible to use vim's syntax highlighting in "live mode"? Or maybe is there an automatic converter from vim's syntax files to highlight's language definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5Fid=1714) could be a solution for you

use vim like tail

Comment: it's not perfect, but it may do the thing after a bit of tweaking (getting rid of vim's window as in vimcat, shortening updatetime for this mode). Thanks.

Comment: found another thread about this http://superuser.com/questions/117841/get-colors-in-less-command maybe you find something better there

Comment: `pygmentize` is nice, but there's the same issue as with `highlight` -- i'd have to write my own syntax file. Since there was no way to simply use my vim syntax file, I ended up writing a bash script with a bunch of sed-ing imitating most important aspects of the mentioned vim syntax file to color piped output from my programs.