# How do I make less look like a terminal to programs attached to its input?

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, less

Questions like ["How do I get grep to pipe color output to less?"](https://superuser.com/questions/36022/getting-colored-results-when-using-a-pipe-from-grep-to-less) explain what flag to give to `grep` so it'll ignore the fact that `less` isn't a regular terminal.  Is there a way to fool an arbitrary program into thinking it's piping to a proper terminal, so I can `less -R` its output and get color?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/108618

Comment: Thanks.  I think that makes mine a duplicate of what you linked.  Can you mark it that way?

Comment: If the linked question was on Super User, then I could and I would. It's on Unix & Linux SE and my goal was to help you regardless of what site the helpful resource is on. Currently a question on SU can be closed as a duplicate of another question posted *on SU*, not elsewhere. Maybe there is a good duplicate on SU, maybe someone will find it. Or maybe someone will comprehensively answer your question here; if he or she uses my link, all the better.